# Delphi Quick Reports - Total Pages

Tags: delphi, quickreports

I'm using QuickReports within my application and would like to have "Page x of x" within the footer. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First prepare the document, so the system itselfs know how many pages will produce.  There's a system variable you can use (no QR at hand to tell you the exact name).

For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //this actually run the report in memory to 
  //calculate things like total page count
  Report1.Prepare;  
  Report1.Print;  //or PreviewModal;
end;
```

Answer (score 9):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.QuickRep1.Prepare;
  Form2.QuickRep1.FTotalPages := Form2.QuickRep1.QRPRinter.PageCount;
  Form2.QuickRep1.QRPrinter.Free;
  Form2.QuickRep1.QuickRep1.QRPrinter := nil;
  Form2.QuickRep1.PreviewModal; // or .Print
end;
```

FTotalPages is declared in Form2 that holds the TQuickRep component.

```
public
    { Public declarations }
    FTotalPages: Integer;
```

Note that the QRPrinter object must be freed after Prepare and before PreviewModal (or .Print) else you will get a memory leak.

In Form2, on the Quickreport1, place a QRLabel, and implement it's onPrint event handler

```
procedure TForm2.QRLabel1Print(sender: TObject; var Value: string);
begin
  Value := 'Page: ' + IntToStr(QuickRep1.QRPrinter.PageNumber) + ' of ' + IntToStr(FTotalPages);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to count the number of pages during preview so when you send it to the printer you can place it in the footer.